# Get service key in Cloud Foundry Java API

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

What I'd like, is to implement in Java, using CF API, something like `cf service-keys (servicename)` and `cf service-key (servicekeyname)` in regular CF commands.

I've been following [this](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/java-client.html) very simple tutorial and I'd like to do something like: `service.getKeys()` or `service.getKey("keyname")` but there are no such methods. And I can't see any class that would help me do that.

Does anyone know the solution and would like to share with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation page you linked to is very out of date. It refers to 1.x versions of the CF Java Client, which is no longer maintained. The [README for the 2.x CF Java Client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) is a better source of information.

Follow the setup instructions in the CF Java Client v2 README to get a `CloudFoundryOperations` object, then you should be able to do something like this:

```
cloudFoundryOperations.services()
    .listServiceKeys(ListServiceKeysRequest.builder()
        .serviceInstanceName("service-instance-name")
        .build())
    .map(ServiceKey::getName)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```